# Edit themes from wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I know we are allowed to used the themes from wordpress and edit them in the theme editor.

However, working in the theme editor is really annoying. Does anybody know if there is a way to download an entire theme file from Wordpress, so that I can customize it in the editor on my laptop?

thanks for the help

Comment: Is there any problem in doing right what you've written: download that file and edit it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Download Plugins and Themes from Dashboard](https://wordpress.org/plugins/download-plugins-dashboard) plugin. it's provides a "download link" in theme's detail page.

Answer (score 1):

While @mohammad's answer is correct, I find it best not to clutter a site with unnecessary plugins, what works best is if you login to your server via FTP or your host's cPanel and download the files that way. It keeps your Wordpress install clean of anything that won't be used too frequently.

If you have any questions on how to do this, your host will be able to guide you without issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions to this problem, you can change theme files through the FTP/SFTP account using Filezilla. or you can access your CPanel account go to the File manager and access your file easily. Other then that you can clone your website to your laptop through any migratory tool after that you can configure your website to the localhost and just make changes in Theme according to your requirement from the Xamp/Wamp folder at your system.